package pythonhighlight isnt rendering in LyX 2.3.7
when I use this package in LyX it doesn't render at all without raising any errors.
the same code on overleaf works completely fine and as intended.
here's a picture from lyx of the code itself and below it is the rendered output using the preview feature of LyX, its the same when compiling and looking at the PDF.

#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
% Necessary Commands:
\usepackage{autobreak}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Set vertical space before and after dislpay equations to be longer for better redability:
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{12pt}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\belowdisplayskip{12pt}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{12pt}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{12pt}}

% Set space between words to be wider:
\spaceskip=1.3\fontdimen2\font plus 1\fontdimen3\font minus 1.5\fontdimen4\font

% Convert the Lyx colors into more pleasent colors:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{12,97,197}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,128,40}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{235,16,16}
\definecolor{brown}{RGB}{154,58,0}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{231,135,26}
\definecolor{purple}{RGB}{94,53,177}

% Convert the QED Symbol at the end of proofs to a solid black square (credit: Yakir Oz):
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

% Make the layout more similar to Hebrew Article, which I am more used to:
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\hspace{0.5cm}\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{0.5cm}} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{20}{20}\bfseries}{\thesection}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{15}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{10pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{10pt}{}

% Correct the reversed parentheses in labels:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{David}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\LRE{#1}}}
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip)}}
\makeatother

% Create disjoint union symbols:
\makeatletter
\def\moverlay{\mathpalette\mov@rlay}
\def\mov@rlay#1#2{\leavevmode\vtop{%
   \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
   \ialign{\hfil$\m@th#1##$\hfil\cr#2\crcr}}}
\newcommand{\charfusion}[3][\mathord]{
    #1{\ifx#1\mathop\vphantom{#2}\fi
        \mathpalette\mov@rlay{#2\cr#3}
      }
    \ifx#1\mathop\expandafter\displaylimits\fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\cupdot}{\charfusion[\mathbin]{\cup}{\cdot}}
\newcommand{\bigcupdot}{\charfusion[\mathop]{\bigcup}{\cdot}}



\newcommand{\kaliLargeLand}{\mathop{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\land}}}}}
\newcommand{\hebtext}[1]{\mbox{\R{\#1}}}

\def\@spart#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \if@RTL\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\huge \bfseries #1\par}%
\nobreak
\vskip 3ex
\@afterheading}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\begin_local_layout
Style Section
    Font
      Series     Medium
      Shape      Smallcaps
      Size       Larger
      Series     Bold
    EndFont
    TocLevel 1
End


Style Section*
    Font
      Series     Medium
      Shape      Smallcaps
      Size      Larger
      Series     Bold
    EndFont
End


Style Solution

    LabelString           "פיתרון: "
End


Style Notation

    LabelString           "סימון  \thetheorem: "
End

Style Theorem

    LabelString           "משפט \thetheorem: "
End

Style Property

    LabelString           "תזכורת: "
End
\end_local_layout
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "David"
\font_sans "default" "David"
\font_typewriter "default" "David"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement H
\paperfontsize default
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 1cm
\bottommargin 3cm
\headheight 0cm
\headsep 0cm
\footskip 2cm
\secnumdepth -2
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0bp
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{python}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      value_a = 1                
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      value_b = 2                       
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      print(value_a + value_b)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{python}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document



Works for me. Can you provide a minimal file that demonstrate the problem?

@UdiFogiel edited my question as requested
